# How to use 2 entity tables together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on school project which is about showing some database properties that I learned.I have 2 entity classes called Person and CarInformation.I want to show Name, Location,WhishedDays from Person and Brand, PlateNumber from CarInformation,together.

I tried generating new class called then I grouped Name, Location, WishedDays,Brand,PlateNumber.In the corresponding controller, I made a List with Select function but failed.

CarInformation Entity Class

```
        public int Id { get; set; }             //Primary key of carinfo table

        public string Brand{ get; set; }
        public string PlateNumber { get; set; }
        public int Milage { get; set; }
        public string InsuranceCompany{ get; set; }
        public double ConsumptionPerMile { get; set; }
        public int DailyPrice { get; set; }
        public DateTime AvailableDates { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Persons")]                      
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }                //foregein key (Person table to carinfo table)
        public virtual Person Persons { get; set; }     //Navigation property


        public List<Sales> Sales { get; set; }
```

Person Entity Class

```
    public int Id { get; set; }                  //primary key of person table

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int WishedDays { get; set; }

    public virtual CarInformation Cars { get; set; }     //Navigation property

    public List<CarInformation> cars { get; set; }  //bir insana ait birden fazla araba olabilir

    public List<Sales> sales { get; set; }
```

Person-CarInformation Class

```
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Location { get; set; }
 public int WishedDays { get; set; }
 public string Brand { get; set; }
 public string PlateNumber { get; set; }
```

Corresponding controller`s Index Method

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {


        var isimler = db.People.
            Select(i => new Person_CarInformation() { Location=i.Location,Name=i.Name, Brand=i.Cars.Brand,PlateNumber=i.Cars.PlateNumber});


        return View(isimler.ToList());
    }
```

When I execute in this circumstances I get this result 
Brand and PlateNumber is empty.

Any advises?

Thank You.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6ppL.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included dependent entity while fetching data. You can get it by changing your code like shown below.

```
   var isimler = db.People.Include("Cars").
            Select(i => new Person_CarInformation() { Location=i.Location,Name=i.Name, Brand=i.Cars.Brand,PlateNumber=i.Cars.PlateNumber});
```

Comment: There is no error. I am just unable to take Name and PlateNumber from CarInformation table. https://imgur.com/pPeNQav

Comment: Have you checked that foreign key data is saved properly in CarInformation table?

Comment: My CarInformation table is above. Foreign key is OwnerId. Can you give me an example query with my tables? For example I want to show just person Name and the its cars. Thank you!